# How to output data from Column A and Column B to Column C automatically in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

When I insert data in column A and Column B, 
It should be automatically merged and added in column C.

```
 A   |   B    |   C  
===================
ABC     CDE     ABCCDE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a concatenation formula into every row in column C.

This is the formula to use if your values are text:

> =A2&B2

I'm assuming that if they were numbers, you would not just want to glue them together.   But you can extend the concatenation, like this:

> =A2&"-"&B2

Here's a worked example, showing these formulas in use:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhYydERaeuKwF_myMLEjAhq8cAKGl1nAeIDJmVNVERc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It will work only for single row. Can you help me to find formula for all rows. So I do not need to write function for every row.

Comment: You can put an arrayformula into the first cell, eg    =arrayformula(A2:A9&B2:B9)      Personally I don't like them, I would rather take responsibility for the formula in each cell myself.   But some people do.

Comment: =ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A)*ISTEXT(B2:B), ("Redirect 301 "&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"http://exrx.net"," ",1) &" "&SUBSTITUTE(B2:B,"http://exrx.net/concrete"," ",1)),IFERROR(1/0)))

This is the thing what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Concatenate function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) to add strings together.

In cell C1, put in `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)`

Then you can copy that result from C1, select the entire C column and paste it. So it should concatenate each row from column A and column B as you expect.